# How to avoid overloading in Power BI when I am using Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, azure-data-lake

I am working on a Power BI project where I am retrieving data from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. I have prepared and designed the project in Power BI Desktop. After that, I published it to Power BI Web. I want the new data that is being entered to appear in the project without loading the old data to avoid heavy server loading. Let's assume I have a 10GB purchase invoices table for a supermarket. I only want it to read the new rows that are added each day without reloading the entire 10GB again.

is it supposed to make change in setting in server? or setting on power bi or Dax function can help, I need some Kayes to understand.

Comment: Have you tried [incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview) ?